# Android auto not working, file sharing in hotspot mode

Tags: android, wifi, wifi-direct, android-auto, tethering

For a long time I observed the problem of transferring data directly between devices without a router and I cannot understand the reasons.

Example 1: you need to transfer a large file via Wifi from one phone to another. If both phones are connected to the router, then this is easy to do with any program such as [SuperBeam](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.majedev.superbeam&hl=ru&gl=US) or [QuickPick](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=gallery.photos.video.quickpic.fastopenphotosvideos&hl=ru&gl=US&pli=1). But when there is no common network nearby, I create an access point on one device, connect a second device to it, then these applications do not work, even if I manually specify the IP and the source port, the client cannot connect.

Example 2: exactly the same situation with Android Auto Wireless, when the car and the phone are connected to the same network, I can easily connect the phone to the car by specifying its IP:

```
    androidAutoWirelessIntent.setClassName("com.google.android.projection.gearhead", "com.google.android.apps.auto.wireless.setup.service.impl.WirelessStartupActivity");
    androidAutoWirelessIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    androidAutoWirelessIntent
            .putExtra("PARAM_HOST_ADDRESS", "192.168.1.155")
            .putExtra("PARAM_SERVICE_PORT", 5288)
```

But nothing happens when I create an access point on the phone and the car connects to it.

what i tried:

1. Ping from terminal - **successful**

   ```
    ~ $  ping 192.168.154.83
    PING 192.168.154.83 (192.168.154.83) 56(84) bytes of data.
    64 bytes from 192.168.154.83: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=556 ms
    64 bytes from 192.168.154.83: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=100 ms
    64 bytes from 192.168.154.83: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=42.4 ms
   ```
2. Create a local server (open port) on one device and connect to it from another (via google chrome) - **successfully**

   ```
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
    while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
        Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
        handleClient(clientSocket);
    }
   ```
3. Run a web server in [X-Plore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lonelycatgames.Xplore&hl=ru&gl=US) on http://192.168.1.174:1111 and access it through google chrome - **successfully**
4. Set static IP from subnet 192.168.1.x - **successful**

What am I missing? If I have a direct line of sight to the device on the network through the ip port, why does nothing work? What is the difference when I am connected through a router or directly through an access point?

Devices: OnePlus 9Pro (androind 11), OnePlus 3T (android 9)

Perhaps this is due: when a client is connected to my phone through my hotspot, this code says that there are no active connections at all.

```
Network ns = connectivityManager.getActiveNetwork(); // === NULL
```